# Confused a bit by “évidemment”

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, anglais

I see *évidemment* used often in French, but don't feel like I quite understand how (or if) it maps to what seem like differing connotations in the English translations. For example, from Wordreference it can mean:

- *obviously, clearly, of course*
- *evidently*
- *needless to say*

I feel like *obviously* and *evidently* have quite different connotations in English. To say, "This or that is so, *obviously*" connotes that anyone who doesn't see this isn't paying attention or might even be dumb.

On the other hand, to say, "*Evidently*, this or that is so" says that there is evidence to back up this information, possibly you're noting a new development, but it doesn't connote that this was obvious.

Does *évidemment* more strongly indicate one of these or the other, or can it encompass both depending on the context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Évidemment](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9videmment)* means "obviously" and "needless to say".

I believe the confusion comes from the ambiguous *evidence*.

An *[évidence](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9vidence)* in French is something that doesn't need to be explained, an obviousness while the English evidence better translate to a French *[preuve](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/preuve)*.

I don't really know the nuance between "obviously" and "evidently" but according to your description, I would say that the closer translation of *evidently* would be *[de toute évidence](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_toute_%C3%A9vidence)*.

Note that the duality of *evidence* was already present in Latin where the word [*evidentia*](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?parola=evidentia) meant either "what is easy to understand, obvious, unequivocal" or "what is clearly visible, what can be trusted."

Comment: *Evidently* carries the idea of "based on the proofs we've seen", so might be faux-amis. Agreed with *obviously* as a good option for *évidemment*.

Comment: I think I am much closer to understanding the differences. So évidemment seems to describe something that is "self-evident" as we would say in English. This is something that is obvious and clearly visible without the need to explain. Merci !

Comment: A big plus for the reference to "de toute évidence" that perfectly translates the "evidently"